# Eliminate repetition in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refactoring

Can I avoid having @thing twice in the following examples of view code? I need to check for `nil` but the view is getting very cluttered.

```
if @thing
  @thing
end
```

or

```
@thing unless @thing.nil?
```

Comment: `@thing if @thing` is probably the shortest I know of.

Comment: Ta, Jakub. Good to know I'm not missing anything obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try use a gem like [andand][1.

Looking at the comments on Alex's response, you might end up with something like:

```
isbn.pubdate.andand.strftime("%d %B '%y")
```

This will return `nil` or the correctly formatted string depending on what pubdate is.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to output @thing or nothing if thing is `nil`, you should be able to just do:

```
<%= @thing %>
```

If @thing is `nil` Ruby will call `Nil.to_s` which returns `""` (i.e. nothing will be output). Otherwise, it calls `@thing.to_s`

Comment: I'll mark this as right because it answers my question. However - my real life example is this: `isbn.pubdate.strftime("%d %B '%y")`. If pubdate is nil, there's an error because you can't call strftime on nil. Do you know any way to avoid checking for nil when there's another method to be called?

I'm moving the ugly into a helper at the moment, but I don't want the helpers to be ugly either!

Comment: @snowangel <%= isbn.pubdate.try(:strftime, "%d %B '%y") %>.  Try is an alias for send() so if you call try <anything> on nil, you just get nil back, so you can chain them too. Foo.bar.try(:baz).try(:to_s) #=> nil

Comment: Ooh, glorious. Though didn't I read somewhere that send / try is BAD?

Comment: try and send aren't bad. But `try` is a bit slow.